# Ember : Clear ember object attribute values

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am implementing crud operation in my Ember project. I passed an object to the component and tried to use the same object for save, update action.

In route I created model as follows,

**routes.js**

```
model() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        employeeList : this.store.findAll("employee"),
        employee : Ember.Object.create(),
      });
}
```

**component: employee-form.js**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="fname">First Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    {{input type="text" value=model.firstName placeholder="First Name"}}
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  {{input type="text" value=model.lastName placeholder="Last Name" }}
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="email">Email:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
   {{input type="text" value=model.email placeholder="Email" }}
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="department">Department: </label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    {{input type="text" value=model.department placeholder="Department" }}
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

I am passing object to component as follows,
**Template.hbs**

```
{{employee-form model=model.employee}}
```

I need to clear the attributes data in object for using it for different operation. I tried to replace the model object with a new ember object and it worked. But I don't think it is a nice way to do, as it is creating new object always.

```
this.set("model", Ember.Object.create());
```

Can anyone help me with best approach to clear ember object attributes values.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rollbackAttributes()`

> **RollbackAttributes** - 
>   If the model hasDirtyAttributes this function will discard any unsaved changes. If the model isNew it will be removed from the store.

```
model.rollbackAttributes();
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, his model isn't a DS.Model instance

Comment: It will not work. I used Ember.Object.create() for creating object. If I use DS createRecord, one empty row will be created in my grid which list all records.